# Putting pictures onto an iPod touch (2nd gen)

Tags: sync, ipod, photo

How do I sync pictures from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop onto my iPod touch easily?

Can someone give me some clear steps without the use of the terminal each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **3. Copying photos to the iPhone or iPod Touch**
>
> Photos can be copied into the Media/DCIM directory in the mobile
>   account. They need to follow the directory and image numbering
>   conventions used by the iPhone/iPod. Multiple image formats are
>   allowed, but they should have a thumbnail (.THM) file which is a 55x55
>   pixel JPG file.
>
> There is a command-line script that can copy images to the iPod Touch
>   or iPhone using ipod-convenience or scp available here.
>
> Note that it is free to use and source available, but not technically
>   open source.

This is taken straight from the ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/syncing%20your%20iphone%20via%20cable). Might be worth reading through that to see what support the ipods and iphones have with ubuntu.

Also [iFuse](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-connect-iphoneipod-touch-using-usbin-karmicjauntyintrepidhardy.html#more-2042) seems like its a good GUI based package to transfer files. Might be worth giving that a shot.

Hope some of this helps.

**EDIT: Also I would always advise searching the Ubuntu documentation for any questions, The documentation is just fantastic! And one of the mains reasons why I love the OS**

Bill